Matplotlib button not responding
I want to add a button that will allow the user to toggle one of four plots between two different data sets, however, the button fails to respond.
The button should call the function which should update the plot... I'm really scratching my head as to why it doesn't. Can anyone shed some light on this?
Here's a minimal reproducible example:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg as tkagg
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.widgets import Button


def qc_manual(filtered_data, figure, canvas):


    def update_plot_colors(axes, lines_to_analyze):
        for ax in axes.flat:
            for line in ax.lines:
                analysis = lines_to_analyze.get(line)
                line.set_color(
                        'blue' if analysis.active and analysis.analysis_type == 'lineblank' else
                        'gray'  # inactive
                )
                line.set_marker('o' if analysis.active else 'x')

    # toggle the 2/40 amu data
    def on_click(event, filtered_data, axes, lines_to_analyze, canvas):

        # clear the lines and axes from the bottom right plot
        axes[1, 1].clear()
        for line in list(lines_to_analyze.keys()):
            if line in axes[1, 1].lines:
                del lines_to_analyze[line]

        title = axes[1, 1].get_title()
        new_title = '2 amu - All Data' if '40 amu - All Data' in title else '40 amu - All Data'
        axes[1,1].set_title(new_title)

        for analysis in filtered_data:

            # filter data for active indices
            mass = '2 amu' if new_title == '2 amu - All Data' else '40 amu'
            x = analysis.time_sec
            y = analysis.raw_data[mass]
            line_color  = 'blue' if analysis.active else 'gray'
            line_marker = 'o' if analysis.active else 'x'
            if new_title == '2 amu - All Data':
                line, = axes[1,1].plot(x, y, marker=line_marker, linestyle='-', picker=5, color=line_color, zorder=2)
            else:
                line, = axes[1,1].plot(x, y, marker=line_marker, linestyle='-', picker=5, color=line_color, zorder=2)
                
            lines_to_analyze[line] = analysis

        # recreate the button
        toggle_button_ax = axes[1, 1].inset_axes([0.75, 1, 0.25, 0.1])
        figure.toggle_button = Button(toggle_button_ax, 'Toggle 2/40 amu')
        figure.toggle_button.on_clicked(lambda event: on_click(event, filtered_data, axes, lines_to_analyze, canvas))

        # formatting
        axes[1,1].set_title(new_title)
        update_plot_colors(axes, lines_to_analyze)
        canvas.draw()


    lines_to_analyze = {} # dictionary to map lines to analyses for efficient lookup

    for ax, (mass, title) in zip(axes.flat, [
        ('4 amu', '4 amu - Gas Standards'),
        ('4 amu', '4 amu - Blanks'),
        ('3 amu', '3 amu - All Data'),
        ('40 amu', '40 amu - All Data')
    ]):
        for analysis in filtered_data:

            # formatting
            line_color  = 'blue' if analysis.active else 'gray'
            line_marker = 'o' if analysis.active else 'x'

            x = analysis.time_sec
            y = analysis.raw_data[mass]

            # draw the data
            line, = ax.plot(x, y, marker=line_marker, linestyle='-', picker=5, color=line_color, zorder=2)

            # store the line and analysis in the dictionary
            lines_to_analyze[line] = analysis

        # formatting
        ax.set_title(title)

    # create a button to toggle between 40 amu and 2 amu
    toggle_button_ax = axes[1, 1].inset_axes([0.75, 1, 0.25, 0.1])
    figure.toggle_button = Button(toggle_button_ax, 'Toggle 2/40 amu')
    figure.toggle_button.on_clicked(lambda event: on_click(event, filtered_data, axes, lines_to_analyze, canvas))

    # update the plot
    update_plot_colors(axes, lines_to_analyze)

    plt.tight_layout()
    canvas.draw()


filtered_data_list = []

for i in range(5):  # replace 5 with the number of analyses you want
    filtered_data = type('filtered_data', (object,), {'raw_data': {}, 'time_sec': [], 'analysis_type': 'lineblank', 'active': True})
    filtered_data.time_sec = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
    filtered_data.raw_data['4 amu'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    filtered_data.raw_data['2 amu'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    filtered_data.raw_data['3 amu'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    filtered_data.raw_data['40 amu'] = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
    filtered_data_list.append(filtered_data)

# setup the main window, figure, and canvas
root = tk.Tk()
figure = plt.figure()
figure.set_size_inches(12, 8)
axes = figure.subplots(2, 2)
canvas = tkagg.FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
canvas.draw()
qc_manual(filtered_data_list, figure, canvas)
root.mainloop()



The problem was that the title variable was empty, so
title = axes[1, 1].get_title()
new_title = '2 amu - All Data' if '40 amu - All Data' in title else '40 amu - All Data'
axes[1,1].set_title(new_title)

was always returning new_title = '40 amu - All Data'.
I added a nonlocal boolean to the main script, plot_40_amu, which is toggled by the button function to determine which plot to show. It works now.
